# Could not explain the non-linear curve in the current in an ideal transformer with square wave voltage source put across it

Tags: transformer, inductor

The top circuit is the circuit in question, the bottom circuit is, I believe and what I have learnt, the equivalent circuit.There is no resistive or core loss of any kind. The core's BH curve is PROBABLY linear (I believe it is, I have no basis for it. As far as I know, if BH curve is not linear, the current should curve up and curve down). Green color in waveforms denotes voltage, yellow denotes current.

The transformer has a "primary inductance of 1H". I believe that means the magnetization current will be calculated using that value (not sure if I am right on that, please confirm). The non-linear curve is due to what? I can't explain it, nor reconcile it with the equivalent circuit.

[image]
Some more info:
The coupling coefficient, which is the only other parameter offered by the simulation software is 0.999. The higher the coefficient (approaching 1) the MORE pronounced the curve is. The higher the load (the lower the resistor value) the MORE pronounced the curve is.

[here is the link to the circuit](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000001%2010.20027730826997%2050%205%2043%0AT%20288%2096%20528%20224%202%201%201%20-12.255887499998629%2012.487499999999821%200.999%0Av%20208%20224%20208%2096%200%202%2060%20125%200%200%200.5%0Ar%20528%2096%20528%20224%200%2010%0Aw%20208%20224%20288%20224%200%0Aw%20208%2096%20288%2096%200%0Aw%20208%20288%20288%20288%200%0Aw%20208%20416%20288%20416%200%0Ar%20528%20288%20528%20416%200%2010%0Av%20208%20416%20208%20288%200%202%2060%20125%200%200%200.5%0Aw%20288%20288%20416%20288%200%0Aw%20288%20416%20416%20416%200%0Al%20416%20288%20416%20416%202%201%200.2191249999999897%0Aw%20416%20288%20528%20288%200%0Aw%20416%20416%20528%20416%200%0A403%20-64%2096%20160%20224%200%201_64_0_4099_160_25.6_0_2_1_3%0A403%20-64%20272%20160%20416%200%208_64_0_4099_160_25.6_0_2_8_3%0A403%20560%2096%20784%20224%200%202_64_0_4099_160_12.8_0_2_2_3%0A403%20560%20288%20784%20432%200%207_64_0_4099_160_12.8_0_2_7_3%0A)

Comment: What other parameters is the simulator using for the transformer?

Comment: You need to confirm about leakage inductance or coupling factor not being unity. You need to put this information in the question and not expect people to guess.

Comment: Why do you think it’s non-linear, and not a transient?

Comment: @Andyaka interestingly, when coupling factor is 0.999, the curve is more pronounced than 0.7

Comment: I'll have to take your word for it but double check and then post a supplementary picture.

Comment: I have provided a link to the circuit

Comment: @eliu No, that link doesn't help because I cannot compare the current upper diagram with this falstad cartoon moving image. Look at the pictures in my answer - are they moving? Do they make analysis easier? Also why oh why is the load 1 ohm now. Concentrate on being consistent or you'll not get to an answer because folk will give up helping if you can't be relied upon to be consistent.

Comment: @Andyaka you can pause the simulation. The link is for you to see all the parameters.

Comment: Listen @eliu I'm not about to start messing with falstad - you need to fix up a circuit with waveforms that show the input primary current when the resistor load is 200 ohms. You need to do this to be consistent with your earlier posting. Remember that this is a Q and A site and not a talking shop forum.

Comment: Why on earth have you changed the frequency to 40 Hz from 60 Hz?

Comment: does all that matter at all? the question is simply "why is that a curvature", whatever the value of resistance, inductance or frequency, there will always be that curvature. I will fix the link

Comment: @eliu Yes, it absolutely matters. It matters 100%. Engineering isn't about messing with a few values and drawing conclusions on a limited data set. You need to be consistent and alter one thing at once. You changed load resistor (200 to 1 ohm), frequency (60 Hz to 40 Hz) and coupling (0.7 to 0.999) and drew totally the wrong conclusion. I also see that falstad appears to model a transformer incorrectly in that it appears to apply leakage inductance to the secondary (you were not to know about that of course).

Comment: I probably tried many values to gauge the nature of the curvature. the screenshot probably had a way larger than 1H primary inductance. So, now, why is there a curvature?

Comment: I've made my answer based on your original pictures and the reasons are still the same.

Comment: Isn't leakage inductance modeled as an inductor in series with the source? the waveform should still be linear.

Comment: @Chu your hint is the most relavent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How falstad.com handles the leakage inductance
[image: How falstad.com handles the leakage inductance]

**Background**
my personal road block or lapse of thought that leads to this question: "leakage inductance can't be it, I change the leakage from 0.1% to 10% to 30% the wave form is still straight lines looking. Besides, isn't leakage inductance just a fix inductance in series with the source in equivalent circuit? it is a fixed element, how does that introduce none linearity into the system"

**My own answer to myself**
A square wave fed into an inductor gets the transient exponential shape, that's it.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that in a transformer with an iron core the input current is not sinusoidal in response to a sinusoidal applied voltage. The output voltage is sinusoidal as the magnetic flux changes in a sinusoidal manner.  The input current contains a large third harmonic component ie. "very peaky".

Re:
A square wave fed into an inductor gets the transient exponential shape, what's the problem here?

One does need to analyse the situation:

1. Draw the equivalent circuit and write the transfer function in terms of the LaPlace transform. eg. Xl = sl instead of Xl = j*omega*l where s = sigma + j*omega
2. Multiply the input v(s) ( = L(v(t) ) by the transfer function then find the inverse laplace transform to get the time waveform.

Comment: Thank you, but the simulation software is very very primitive, my moment of stupidity was even greater. The simulation is not counting none of that eddie current core loss saturation nonlinear BH curves. This question is due to a mistake as simple as passing a step into an RL circuit and what the wave form would look like.